# How to update the screen by rendering the new elements found in the search

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a search screen and the function works fine but i want to update the screen when an item that match the query is found in the array of notes.

What I have is a search bar that get the query and when the state is changed the `componentDidUpdate` will filter through an array of notes, and the notes that contain that query will be added to the new array called `filteredNotes`. What I am trying to do is to update the screen, each time an item is found or to implement an `enter` button so it wont use the processing power by rendering each time a character is typed, either way will do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the entire component.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    state = {
        search: '',
        notes: [],
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.getItems();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this._isMounted) {
            if (this.state.search !== prevProps.search) {
                let filteredNotes = this.state.notes.filter(el => el.name.includes(this.state.search));
                this.state.notes = filteredNotes;
            }
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }
    async getItems() {
        this.setState({ loadingNotes: true });
        const notesObj = await getAllNotes();
        this.getNotes(notesObj);
        this.setState({ loadingNotes: false })
    }
    getNotes(notesObj) {
        for (let i = 0; i < notesObj.length; i++) {
            let note = {
                name: notesObj[i].note.name,
            }
            this.state.notes.push(note);
        }
    }


    render() {
        const { search } = this.state;
        const { notes } = this.state;
        const { navigate } = this.props;
        return (
            <View>
                <Searchbar
                    placeholder="Search"
                    onChangeText={(query) => { this.setState({ search: query }); }}
                    value={search}
                />
                <NoteFlatList
                    data={notes.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1)}
                    navigate={navigate}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that what i am trying to do, when i filter the notes, i set the `state.notes = filteredNotes`. Does that cause a change of the state and trigger the re-render of the NoteFlatList, which is a FlatList in itself?

Comment: Try replace `this.state.notes = filteredNotes;` by `this.setState({ notes: filteredNotes })`

Comment: That will result in this `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update 
depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`